# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from py_expression_eval import *

def f(exp, var, x0):
    p = Parser()
    result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
    return result
a = 0
b = 4
error = 10
i = 0
while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):
    c = (a + b) / 2
    fa = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a)
    fc = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', c)
    if(fc == 0):
        raiz = c
        break
    elif(fa * fc < 0):
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    raiz = c
    i += 1
    error = abs(fc)
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)
print(raiz)
print(i)
print(f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x',raiz))

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
print(x)
plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))
plt.plot(a, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a), 'or')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Me dice el error del título al tratar de graficar después de implementar el evaluador de expresiones, antes no me daba problema con el siguiente código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import py_expression_eval

def f(x):
    return x**3 -2 * x ** 2 - 1
a = 0
b = 4
error = 10
i = 0
while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):
    c = (a + b) / 2
    fa = f(a)
    fc = f(c)
    if(fc == 0):
        raiz = c
        break
    elif(fa * fc < 0):
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    raiz = c
    i += 1
    error = abs(fc)
    print("Intervalo ("+str(a) + "," + str(b) +")" )
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)
print(raiz)
print(i)
print(f(2.2055694311857224))
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme a que funcione con el expression `eval` se lo agradezco de antemano.

El mensage de error completo es este:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\bisection3.py", line 34, in
>
> `plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))`
>
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\bisection3.py", line 7, in f
>
> `result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})`
>
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval__init__.py", line 122, in evaluate
>       nstack.append(f(n1, n2))
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Si trato de convertir `x` a `int` antes de pasarlo a la función que va graficar, me da el mismo error del titulo, es algo que tiene que ver con el tipo de dato pero nose que es :(

Comment: Esto es el metodo de biseccion en python lo hice exactamente igual que como en este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezREOgAA6jg solo que quiero mejorar la parte de f(x) para que tenga evaluador de expresiones

Comment: Bienvenido, @Daniel V. Cuando hagas una pregunta, asegúrate que el código quede bien marcado y bien identado para que sea legible. Así mismo, deberías añadir el mensaje de error completo para saber en qué línea se produce el error.

Comment: ...y mejor que hacerte autocomentarios, añade esa información a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error común cuando se mezclan arrays de `NumPy` y ciertas operaciones matemáticas nativas o definidas en la biblioteca estándar de Python como `math.sqrt()`.

En tu caso el problema se origina en la línea:

```
plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))
```

El problema curiosamente es la operación de potenciación , `^` la que te causa el problema ya que espera escalares como parámetros de entrada pero le estas pasando un array de `Numpy`:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
```

La solución en estos casos suele ser sustituir la función problemática por su equivalente en la librería `Numpy`y que si acepta como parámetro de entrada arrays de `NumPy`. En este caso el análogo de `^` es `numpy.power()`, para ello puedes modificar el operador que usará `evaluate` modificando `ops2`:

```
parser.ops2['^'] = np.power
```

El código quedaría así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from py_expression_eval import *

def f(exp, var, x0):
    p = Parser()
    p.ops2['^'] = np.power
    result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
    return result

a = 0
b = 4
error = 10
i = 0
while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):
    c = (a + b) / 2
    fa = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a)
    fc = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', c)
    if(fc == 0):
        raiz = c
        break
    elif(fa * fc < 0):
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    raiz = c
    i += 1
    error = abs(fc)
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)
print(raiz)
print(i)
print(f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x',raiz))

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
print(x)
plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))
plt.plot(a, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a), 'or')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Lo que muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, lo voy a probar cuando llegue a mi casa =)

Comment: Disculpa @FJSevilla si por ejemplo yo quisiera hacer el sin de algo o el coseno de algo, tambien tendria que indicarle que lo hiciera por medio del equivalente en NumPy verdad? entonces haria lo mismo dar un nombre de variable como nose opsSin? y asignarselo, o debe ser un nombre especifico asi como me dijiste que ops2 :p gracias denuevo

Comment: intente hacer p.op3['sin']= np.sin pero me sale error dice que parser no tiene atributo ops3, y esta es la funcion que estoy usando f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1','x',x)) como haces para saber que nombre darle? asi como hiciste p.ops2

Comment: Te he respondido ya en tu [otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52844/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-2), como explico en ella más ampliamente `ops2` es en realidad un diccionario que es un atributo de la clase `Parser` y que se usa para especificar que función se usa para resolver cada expresión parseada, en el caso de la función `sin` se encuentra en el atributo `ops1` por lo que debes usar `p.ops1['sin'] = np.sin`.