# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (2)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hola otra vez yo con el mismo error pero en diferente lugar.

Veran tengo el siguiente codigo

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from py_expression_eval import *


def f(exp, var, x0):

    p = Parser()
    p.ops2['^'] = np.power
    result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
    return result

a = 0

b = 4

error = 10

i = 0

while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):

    c = (a + b) / 2
    fa = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a)
    fc = f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', c)
    if(fc == 0):
        raiz = c
        break
    elif(fa * fc < 0):
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    raiz = c
    i += 1
    error = abs(fc)
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)
print(raiz)

print(i)

print(f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x',raiz))


x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)

print(x)

plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))

plt.plot(a, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1', 'x', a), 'or')

plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Funciona perfectamente pero el problema que tenia antes era el mismo del titulo, un buen compañero de este sitio me colaboro diciendome lo siguiente:
Es un error común cuando se mezclan arrays de NumPy y ciertas operaciones matemáticas nativas o definidas en la biblioteca estándar de Python como math.sqrt().

En tu caso el problema se origina en la línea:

```
plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * x^2 - 1','x',x))
```

El problema curiosamente es la operación de potenciación , ^ la que te causa el problema ya que espera escalares como parámetros de entrada pero le estas pasando un array de Numpy:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
```

La solución en estos casos suele ser sustituir la función problemática por su equivalente en la librería Numpyy que si acepta como parámetro de entrada arrays de NumPy. En este caso el análogo de ^ es numpy.power(), para ello puedes modificar el operador que usará evaluate modificando ops2:

```
parser.ops2['^'] = np.power
```

y le entendi pero a la hora de intentar graficar con la funcion

```
f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1','x',x)
```

me vuelve a aparecer el error del titulo por causa del sin ya que me imagino que tampoco puede recibir un array numpy e intente solucionarlo diciendo que `p.ops3['sin'] = np.sin`
pero me dice que parser no tiene atributo `ops3`, o sea como el que me respondio si le puede poner ops2 y le agarro? Como se que nombre darle despues de parser. Me da pena preguntar esto porque seguramente es muy obvio pero es que apenas estoy aprendiendo python :,v

El mensage de error completo es el siguiente:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\bisection3.py", line 36, in 
>       plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1','x',x))
>
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\bisection3.py", line 8, in f
>       result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval__init__.py",
>   line 133, in evaluate
>       nstack.append(f(n1))
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez me faltó explicar un poco mejor de donde saco `op2`, en realidad es un [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) de Python perteneciente a la clase `Parser` donde la clave es una cadena como `+` o `^` y como valor tiene la función/operación correspondiente que se usará para resolver la expresíon, usando la biblioteca `math` o métodos implementados en la propia biblioteca `py_expressions_eval`. Existen otros diccionarios que se usan con el mismo fin y que pueedes modificar para adaptarlo a tus necesidades, la clave está en saber donde se encuentra cada cosa.

En el caso de la función seno se encuentra en el atributo `op1`con la clave `sin` y usa `math.sin` para resolver Como en el caso anterior debes especificar que se use `numpy.sin` en su lugar para poder trabajar con arrays como parámetros de entrada a la función.

Te dejo una lista con los diccionarios que se usan como atributos en la clase `Parser` para especificar las funciones usadas para resolver cada expresión por si necesitas modificar otros operadores o funciones:

```
self.ops1 = {
    'sin': math.sin,
    'cos': math.cos,
    'tan': math.tan,
    'asin': math.asin,
    'acos': math.acos,
    'atan': math.atan,
    'sqrt': math.sqrt,
    'log': math.log,
    'abs': abs,
    'ceil': math.ceil,
    'floor': math.floor,
    'round': round,
    '-': self.neg,
    'exp': math.exp,
}

self.ops2 = {
    '+': self.add,
    '-': self.sub,
    '*': self.mul,
    '/': self.div,
    '%': self.mod,
    '^': math.pow,
    ',': self.append,
    '||': self.concat,
    "==": self.equal,
    "!=": self.notEqual,
    ">": self.greaterThan,
    "<": self.lessThan,
    ">=": self.greaterThanEqual,
    "<=": self.lessThanEqual,
    "and": self.andOperator,
    "or": self.orOperator
}

self.functions = {
    'random': random,
    'fac': self.fac,
    'min': min,
    'max': max,
    'pyt': self.pyt,
    'pow': math.pow,
    'atan2': math.atan2,
    'concat':self.concat
}

self.consts = {
    'E': math.e,
    'PI': math.pi,
}

self.values = {
    'sin': math.sin,
    'cos': math.cos,
    'tan': math.tan,
    'asin': math.asin,
    'acos': math.acos,
    'atan': math.atan,
    'sqrt': math.sqrt,
    'log': math.log,
    'abs': abs,
    'ceil': math.ceil,
    'floor': math.floor,
    'round': round,
    'random': self.random,
    'fac': self.fac,
    'exp': math.exp,
    'min': min,
    'max': max,
    'pyt': self.pyt,
    'pow': math.pow,
    'atan2': math.atan2,
    'E': math.e,
    'PI': math.pi
}
```

Es simplemente un fragmento del código de la biblioteca `py_expressions_eval`y que puedes obtener al completo desde [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py_expression_eval) o el el [repositorio de GitHub](https://github.com/AxiaCore/py-expression-eval/).

Por lo tanto tu código debería ser algo así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from py_expression_eval import *

def f(exp, var, x0):
    p = Parser()
    p.ops2['^'] = np.power
    p.ops1['sin'] = np.sin
    result = p.parse(exp).evaluate({var:x0})
    return result
a = 0
b = 4
error = 10
i = 0
while(error>1e-8 and i!=100):
    c = (a + b) / 2
    fa = f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1','x',a)
    fc = f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1', 'x', c)
    if(fc == 0):
        raiz = c
        break
    elif(fa * fc < 0):
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    raiz = c
    i += 1
    error = abs(fc)
    print("Iteracion",i,". Raiz aproximada:",raiz)
print(raiz)
print(i)
print(f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1', 'x',raiz))

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
print(x)
plt.plot(x, f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1','x',x))
plt.plot(a, f('x^3 -2 * sin(x^2) - 1', 'x', a), 'or')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Lo cual muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale gracias FJ voy a probarlo y porfavor esta pendiente que probablemente te necesite otraves jaja :)

Comment: oye mira que funciona perfecto pero intente usar tan(x) y la grafica ya no me la quiere hacer, en la misma funcion que tengo solo le cambio el sin por tan 'x^3 -2 * tan(x^2) - 1' y pues todavia me calcula la raiz pero la grafica esta quedando mala tu sabrias decirme porque?

Comment: @DanielV no tengo posibilidad ahora mismo de probar con `matplotlib` pero creo que el problema no es que no lo grafique (probablemente si lo hace) sino una cuestion de escala. Piensa que tu código genera un valor de `a` de 1.2533141373155001, eso nos da como valor de `y` al sustituir en  `x^3 -2 * tan(x^2) - 1`: -7.06022864243e+15, es decir -5398604169258.937. El rango es demasiado amplio debido a la naturaleza de la función. En cuando pueda investigaré con `matplotlib` a ver que se puede hacer pero creo que este es el problema.

Comment: si tienes razon es por eso, hace la grafica pero "mal", tratare tambien de que funcione, si consigues algo avisame porfa, gracias :)

Comment: has conseguido algo? No encuentro como hacer para que grafique algo tan simple como esa funcion x^3 -2 * tan(x^2) - 1, sera mejor cambiar de libreria para graficar? tu cual conoces aparte de matplotlib?

Comment: @DanielV La función la puedes graficar sin problemas, el problema es el punto ya que para poder graficarlo junto a la función necesitas un rango extremadamente grande para el eje y, vas a terminar 'desformando' la función al reescalar, ten en cuenta que la función tiende a infinito para ciertos valores de x. Noi creo que sea un problema de librería. Si intentas hacer lo mismo en papel te encontrarás con el mismo problema. Puedes graficar solo la parte adyacente al punto o dibujar la función rompiendo el eje y como aparece [aquí](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html).

Comment: vale gracias man voy a mirar esa pagina y te cuento como me fue :)

Comment: man mira que tenias razon la funcion se grafica perfectamente pero cuando intento graficarla junto al punto donde esta la raiz, se deforma, me diste dos soluciones graficar solo la parte adyacente al punto o dibujar la funcion rompiendo el eje y pero no comprendo como aplicar lo que esta en esa pagina en mi codigo XD podrias decirme como graficar solo la parte adyacente al punto creo que es la solucion mas sencilla? Yo igual intentare hacerlo aqui, gracias otraves por tu ayuda me ha servido mucho :)