# Graficar vectores en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Verán, por parte de la uni me pidieron realizar una calculadora de números complejos que incluya ciertas funciones avanzadas, entre ellas debe seleccionarse un número complejo y graficarlo en un plano (x,y) donde "x" sea el coeficiente real y "y" el coeficiente imaginario. El caso es que lo estoy realizando en python con la ayuda de las librerías:

`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Pues son las que están dedicadas a un ámbito científico en Python. He encontrado tutoriales sobre como realizar gráficos de todo tipo, pero lo que a mi me interesa es graficar específicamente vectores (ya que un número imaginario es un vector ubicado en un plano cartesiano), ya sea en la forma binómica, es decir, dado su componente en "x" y su componente en "y", o ya sea en su forma polar, es decir, dado su ángulo "a" y su longitud "r".

No he encontrado información al respecto en ningún lado y ciertamente me he roto la cabeza para no lograr nada ya que nada me ha dado resultado. Si me preguntan, hice el siguiente código pero sin ningún éxito:

```
#imports
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#La clase define in objeto del tipo par ordenado, que se inicializa
#con sus componentes a y b, de la forma binómica de un número complejo:
#(a+ib)
class ParOrdenado:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.real = int(a)
        self.imaginario = int(b)

#La funcion graficar se supone debe tomar esos valores y usarlos para 
#crear un vector que vaya de 0 a el componente respectivo de X y Y
def graficarComp(e):
    limx = int(e.real)
    limy = int(e.imaginario)
    x = int(np.arange(0,limx,0.1))
    y = int(np.arange(0,limy,0.1))

    #Una vez hecho eso debe realizar el gráfico del vector
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('(',elemento.real,",",elemento.imaginario,")")
    plt.show()

#Estoy trabajando con una cola para ingresar los elementos,
#en este caso es solo uno, para realizar la prueba
cola = deque([])
x = ParOrdenado(1,2)
print(x.real,",",x.imaginario)
cola.append(x)
for i in range(len(cola)):
    f = cola[i]
    graficarComp(f)

print("Fin del programa...")
input()
```

El programa me manda un error, que es el siguiente:

```
 1 , 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graficarVector.py", line 32, in <module>
    graficarComp(f)
  File "graficarVector.py", line 17, in graficarComp
    x = int(np.arange(0,limx,0.1))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Sé tambien que ya se trato ese tema [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52660/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars), pero ciertamente no me quedó muy claro y no resolví el problema, espero abriendo este tema quede la pregunta de una manera más específica, saludos cordiales a todos :)

Comment: Sin entrar a ver el algoritmo el error es muy claro estas intentando convertir un array de mas de un elemento en un entero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pintar campos vectoriales matplotlib te da el método `quiver`.

Es un poco complicado de usar. El siguiente código lo usa para pintar un solo vector:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#La clase define in objeto del tipo par ordenado, que se inicializa
#con sus componentes a y b, de la forma binómica de un número complejo:
#(a+ib)
class ParOrdenado:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.real = int(a)
        self.imaginario = int(b)

#La funcion graficar se supone debe tomar esos valores y usarlos para 
#crear un vector que vaya de 0 a el componente respectivo de X y Y
def graficarComp(e):
    # Coordenadas del vector
    x, y = e.real, e.imaginario

    # Limites de la figura
    izda = min(-1, x-1)
    dcha = max(1, x+1)
    abajo = min(-1, y-1)
    arriba = max(1, y+1)

    # El metodo quiver pinta vectores, pero para que salgan de las
    # dimensiones correctas hay que usar los parámetros angles, scale y scale_units

    plt.quiver([x], [y], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)

    # Pintamos lineas que pasan por el origen de coordenadas
    plt.axhline(0, color='black')
    plt.axvline(0, color='black')

    # Fijamos límites, etiquetas y títulos
    plt.xlim([izda, dcha])
    plt.ylim([abajo, arriba])
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('({},{})'.format(e.real,e.imaginario))
    plt.show()


ejemplo = ParOrdenado(1,2)
graficarComp(ejemplo)
```

Este ejemplo produce el siguiente resultado (el color de fondo y el aspecto puede depender de tu configuración de matplotlib):

[image: Resultado]

No sé si tu intención es mostrar varios vectores en la misma figura. `quiver()` puede hacerlo. El primer parámetro de `quiver()` sería la lista de todas las partes reales de los vectores, y el segundo la lista de todas las partes imageinarias.